# Transformation hotkeys stopped working in blender 2.82

Tags: 3d-view, transforms, shortcut

There is something strange going on with my blend file. Although pressing <kbd>S</kbd> in *Edit Mode* to scale my meshes works just fine. In *Object Mode* <kbd>S</kbd> doesn't do anything.

This started to happen with a very large blend file and I'm not sure what option I might have accidentally triggered to cause this. I'm not allowed to scale new objects or even old ones in *Object Mode*. The same applies for <kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd> (grab and rotate). When I go to the *Object Properties* to edit the properties, I'm able to rotate and move the object though.

**Q:** Is there any way getting the hotkeys to work again?

A file with removed content and only a single cube (and maybe some shaders and textures as its still 5mb)
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't accidentally locked the location, rotation and scale (Lock icon behind the properties)?

Comment: @RobertGützkow nothing is locked in the properties pannels of a object, it also happens on new objects

Comment: Please upload a modified version of your affected project, so that it only contains a simple object like a cube but still demonstrates the issue. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @RobertGützkow just uploaded it, link in question text

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about expreimental unreleased version of Blender.

Comment: Blender is in constant development many people work with development releases(even famous movies where made used non final versions) keep this question open so blender velopment can go on, as for now i want to know if it is some setting. If no one knows of a setting i post in bugtrack of blender.

Comment: @user219279, I canceled the vote because it seems the version is not relevant in this case(see the answer below), however some questions about issues in experimental versions have little value since the answers might change very quickly or become irrelevant as the daily build are... daily. I have nothing against using experimental versions, I just think that questions about them here have little value.

Comment: Well i have used Blender dev version questions they are usually for a  tillrelease period practical ater that people wound stumble on it anymore (or it be still a bug).
I think its better to ask here, you found the answer and so we didnt took time of blender developers which is OK i think.

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck the Locations option in the Tool Settings bar: [image]

or in the Tool and Workspace tab in the Properties Editor:

[image]

Comment: I must hace accidently clicked it, I wonder the purpose. 
And i wonder f this behavior is a bug.
Should it be called Limit instead of options ?  (options of what??), a textual bug perhaps, maybe some room for improvement. Do you know when those option settings are handy ?

Comment: Not a bug at all. That's a very handy feature.You can [move objects uniformly away or towards some center by scaling them with this options for example](https://imgur.com/XJfH2M9), or switch them places without rotating if you use rotate with this.

Comment: Bug as wrong naming for such a future i think, options is to general.

Comment: It could be called 'Tool Options' probably, but then the settings work on transform operators as well that are not 'tools' as oposed to tools in the toolbar... I think the naming is OK. You find out about it and then you know - that's all.